Position BEM elements regard to a block
im new in css and BEM, im trying to create a small web app using this BEM naming convention and two questions about my code related with BEM.

I use a page block to take all user screen and the page__body, page__header and page__selection elements to display content inside this block. is correct use those block elements nested? I mean for example, in the html code i created page__selection for position the tag  regard  that is a page__content. I feel like I am creating a dependency between block elements instead of a block-element relationships.

BEM let you create blocks that you can reused so i created list block because use a lot flexbox display. But i think this produces too many clases and make my code sematically hard to understand what do your think?


HTML CODE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="page">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>a title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <!--adapt width of screen-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=width-device, initial_scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body class="page__body">
    <header class="page__header">
        titleHeader
    </header>
        <div class="page__content list list--flex-direction--row">
            <aside class="page__selection list">
                <div class="list__list-items list ">
                    List of name list
                </div>
                <div class="list__list-buttons list list--flex-direction--row ">
                    <div class="button button--background-color--green">
                        create
                    </div>
                    <div class="button button--background-color--green">
                        remove
                    </div>

                </div>
            </aside>
            <main class="page__show-list-content list list--background-color--brown">
                Main list
            </main>
        </div>

    
    <footer>Contact </footer>

</body>
</html>

CSS CODE
/*Principal block that represent principal page*/
.page {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

/*Elements used for geometry*/
.page__body {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

.page__selection {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}

.page__header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    background-color:aquamarine;
}

.page__content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
}

.page__selection {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}

.page__show-list-content {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*Second block represent a list that containt elements*/
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.list__list-items {
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    background-color:gray;
}

.list__list-buttons {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color:red;
}



.list--flex-direction--row {
    flex-direction:row;
}

.list--background-color--brown {
    background-color: brown;
}

/*Third block represent a button*/
.button {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;    
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:fit-content;
    height:fit-content;
}

.button--background-color--green {
    background-color:green;
}

For the first question i tried official BEM site but has simple examples that dont help about nested elements and position those respect a block.

BEM must die. .

@Kosh do you have any alternative to BEM that you use?

imho, HTML5 and CSS both are pretty semantic and powerful themselves. Block-element-modifier concept along with its naming convention leads to unnecessarily bloated codebase. As you can see in your own example. So I don't use BEM, and I don't look for an alternative. I use HTML tags and attributes according to their meaning; I use nested CSS for component-specific styles; HTML-templates and shadow DOM for reusable and custom components.
